# Can pip or Poetry be told not to install GPL-licensed packages?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-poetry

We were surprised during a recent release review to discover some GPL packages had been installed as transitive dependencies. Is there a way to configure either pip or poetry installs to fail on certain license types? Our legacy services use pip and new services use poetry. Alternately, is there at least a good way to list the licenses of all dependencies, including transitive dependencies?

Comment: There are two different questions in here (and the "list transitive dependencies" one has a very easy answer, as listing the complete dependency set is effectively what `pip freeze` does when run after a blank install).

Comment: ...btw, personally I use [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) as my package manager, not just for Python packages but for *everything* -- it also supports downloading dependencies from other ecosystems, including Go/Java/etc., and provides a consistent view of the entire dependency set including C libraries, tools used to build them, etc., and it's easy to run code over that tree, to check `meta.license` for each element. Not adding an answer, though, as Nix isn't going to be easy for anyone who's currently running a more conventional stack to adopt.

Comment: Pip cannot be configured to take licenses into account.  I don't know about Poetry, but I'd be surprised if it offered that option.

Comment: AFAIK, `pip freeze` doesn't list the licenses, just the package names and versions.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't, but once you have names and versions, pypi has an API that can be used to get the rest of the metadata.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: Combine `pip freeze` with `pip show` to get the licenses of installed packages.

Comment: We use [liccheck](https://github.com/dhatim/python-license-check) in our CI to ensure license compliance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure either pip or poetry installs to fail on certain license types?

There is not.

> Alternately, is there at least a good way to list the licenses of all dependencies, including transitive dependencies?

The [`pip-licenses`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/) project will list the licenses of all dependencies:

```
$ pip-licenses
 Name    Version  License
 Django  2.0.2    BSD
 pytz    2017.3   MIT
```

Comment: Just to have it a little more visible - there is a similar package called [`liccheck`](https://github.com/dhatim/python-license-check) that allows you to define white- and black-lists of licenses which it checks against. It can be plugged into CI/CDs to assert that only certain licenses are used.